# Check Database for username or password OledDb Connection

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I'm trying to check a database that i have connect to my program for user name and password i have my query made but how would i go about checking it against a table.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Menu m1 = new Menu();
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=UserAccounts.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from UserAccounts where Username = " +userBox.Text + " and Password] = " + Password.Text + "");
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                this.Hide();
                m1.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you better explain in english what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: I have Microsoft Access file that has username and passwords. I'm trying to check what the user has entered in both the username and password field to see if they are in the database and to allow them Access if they have the correct username and password @Avitus

Comment: Oh goodness. Another super-insecure and password-leaking home-rolled system :-/ In any case, `Password]` is invalid SQL syntax. Try using a `[` too. Then look up "prepared statement" .. and then you'll actually want to query the database (run the command) and do something with the result.

Comment: Use OleDbParameters on your OleDbCommand object.

Comment: @LarsTech i got this far how do i check it against in an if statement ?
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query,conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username ", userBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password ", Password.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    this.Hide();
                    m1.Show();
                }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close already, let's just modify it a little bit:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Menu m1 = new Menu();
    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=UserAccounts.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from UserAccounts where Username = @Username and Password = @Password"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", userBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password.Text);

                using (OleDbDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (r.HasRows)
                    {
                        // do something here
                    }
                }
            }
            this.Hide();
            m1.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to check if a username and password exists you could do like this

```
public bool IsValid(string username, string password)
        {
            string connectionString = @"...connectionstring";


            string SQL = "SELECT * FROM UserAccounts where [Username]='" + username + "' and [Password]='" + password + "'";

            OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);

            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(SQL);
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            conn.Open();

            OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```